# How to save state within a microsoft outlook 2010 addin?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have a Ribbon Edit Box within my outlook 2010 add-in, and I would like to save state, the user will input some text, and click a check box to store that text so that they will not have to reenter it every time they open Outlook.

More specifically would this kind of thing be stored in application data? ini files? maybe the registry? A C# code example would be greatly appreciated.

My question is more about best practices then implementation, although implementation details would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in LocalApplicationData path.  Use System.Envrionment.SpecialFolders to get the path.  Just create a folder under that special folder for your add-in data, and create a file to store whatever you need there.

Comment: Could you include an explanation as to why that folder? I've seen discussion on sandboxing and the like, and I'm trying to understand the concepts behind it. Maybe some other relevant resource?

Comment: There are other special folders that may work as well.  That one is for users setting which don't roam.  That is, if they log onto another workstation your plugin won't find the settings file.  Of course outlook might not even be on that other workstation.  If you want the settings to roam with the user, I think ApplicationData would be fine.